# Find every word between >< with regex?

Tags: c#, xml, regex

I have an xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

<string name="name">word1</string>
<string name="namee">word2</string>
<string name="nameee">word3</string>

</resources>
```

I want to find every word between > <. Therefore word1, word2 and word3.
I have written some code but that regex expression find only the first word (word1).

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(openFileDialog1.FileName);
            string s = sr.ReadToEnd();
            richTextBox1.Text = s;
        }

        string txt = richTextBox1.Text;
        string foundWords = Regex.Match(txt, @"\>(\w+)\<").Groups[1].Value;
        richTextBox1.Text = foundWords;

    }
```

I want to find every word between > < and display it in a rich textbox.

Comment: .NET has built-in XML parsers. Use those.

Comment: so, what problems are you having?

Comment: possible duplicate of [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: Your input should not be an `XML` document and your requirement will be acceptable, if it's an `XML` document, I think you can do all the tasks with some XML parser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use method `Regex.Matches()` to capture `MatchCollection`

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(openFileDialog1.FileName);
        string s = sr.ReadToEnd();
        richTextBox1.Text = s;
    }

    string txt = richTextBox1.Text;
    var foundWords = Regex.Matches(txt, @"(?<=>)(\w+?)(?=<)");
    richTextBox1.Text = string.Join("\n", foundWords.Cast<Match>().Select(x=>x.Value).ToArray());
}
```

Comment: It is giving me that error Error:
The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'string.Join<System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match>(string, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match>)' and 'string.Join(string, params object[])'

Comment: @orglce i lost Select :) fixed

Comment: How to find strings with spaces. for ex:
<string name="app">App Name</string>

Comment: write new regex, f.e. `(?<=>)([\w ]+?)(?=<)`

Comment: how to find strings with multiple words? for ex:
<string name="app">App Name App Name</string>

Answer (score 2):

You should probably look at parsing XML with something else baked into .NET.

Having said that:

You're only getting the first one because you're using Match. (matches a single value)
Try using Matches instead (returns a collection of Match values that you can iterate through).

Try:

```
list<String> foundWords = new List<String>();
var foundMatches = regex.matches(txt, @"\>(\w+)<");
foreach(match m in foundMatches)
{
     foundWords.add(m.Groups[1].Value);
}
//do something with list of foundWords
```

Comment: This is an awful suggestion to parse XML with regular expressions - if OP wanted to use regular expression for something it does not mean it suitable for task.